# gradle not using compile time dependencies when building

Tags: build, gradle

Hi guys I'm new to gradle and have the following issue.

When I use the java plugin and invoke **$gradle build** on my project it does not put my third party dependencies on the classpath. My build.gradle file looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/main/web"]

repositories {
  flatDir name: 'thirdParty', dirs: 'C:/dev/repo'
}

dependencies {
  compile files('log4j-1.2.12.jar', 'gson-1.7.1.jar')
}
```

and the error output from gradle is the following

```
C:\dev\gradling\TestProject\src\main\web\java\org\gradle\example\simple\HelloWorld2.java:3: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.Gson;
                      ^
C:\dev\gradling\TestProject\src\main\web\java\org\gradle\example\simple\HelloWorld2.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Gson
location: class org.gradle.example.simple.HelloWorld2
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         ^
C:\dev\gradling\TestProject\src\main\web\java\org\gradle\example\simple\HelloWorld2.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Gson
location: class org.gradle.example.simple.HelloWorld2
         Gson gson = new Gson();
```

I have stated where my repo jars live and told it that when it compiles it must include the above mentioned jars.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency declarations are incorrect. You can *either* specify a `flatDir` repo and use the usual dependency syntax for external dependencies (`group:module:version`), *or* use the `files` method together with correct file paths (then you don't need to declare a repository). In the former case, you may leave out the dependency's group. For example:

```
repositories {
    flatDir name: 'thirdParty', dirs: 'C:/dev/repo'
}

dependencies {
    compile ':log4j:1.2.12'
}
```

For more information, consult the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Thanks, the colon notation did the trick. Is there no way you can just straight hard code the jar file that you want to include in your example above?

Comment: As I said, you can use `files("absolute/or/relative/path/to/the.jar")`. For example, if the Jars are located relative to the build's root directory, you would do `files("$rootDir/some/path")`. If you follow this approach, you won't need to declare a `flatDir` repository.